# Migrating to MYSQLI : How to fitch result of query in while(list()) method instead of foreach() method?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, migration

I have very large  PHP website, about 3000+ PHP files, all files are linked to main class named (lib.inc.php) which includes :

```
config.inc.php
users.inc.php
mysql.inc.php
```

I am doing quick migration from MYSQL to MYSQLI , and I am planning to do very minimal changes in MYSQL part, I did found many MYSQLI Classes which I can replace it with my old mysql.inc.php , but thats was not the big part of the job ... The big part is I have to change the code of the queries in almost each PHP file, I have around 3 to 5 MYSQL Queries which is currently in the following format structure :

```
$query = "
SELECT USER_ID,USER_NAME,USER_EMAIL,USER_LEVEL,USER_REG_DATE,USER_LAST_ACCESS,USER_LAST_IP 
FROM USERS_TBL
LIMIT 0,20
";

$sth = $dbh -> do_query($query);


while (list($USER_ID,USER_NAME,USER_EMAIL,USER_LEVEL,USER_REG_DATE,USER_LAST_ACCESS,USER_LAST_IP) = $dbh -> fetch_array($sth)) {
// Do some thing with the result and print it
}
```

IN mysql.inc.php : I have the following Functions related to the above code :

```
function do_query($query) {
  $this->sth = mysql_query($query,$this->dbh);
  return $this->sth;
}

function fetch_array($sth) {

  $this->row = mysql_fetch_array($sth);

  return $this->row;
}
```

My question is :

How to migrate the above code from MYSQL to MYSQLI keeping in mind that I dont want to change the structure of loop part , as I want to all my while loops remain the same in all 3000+ PHP files , specially this part :

```
while (list($USER_ID,$USER_NAME,$USER_EMAIL,$USER_LEVEL,$USER_REG_DATE,$USER_LAST_ACCESS,USER_LAST_IP) = $dbh -> fetch_array($sth)) {
// Do some thing with the result and print it
}
```

In the current MYSQLI classes which I found in the net , all statements witch dealing with fetching array it has the following structure:

```
/**
 * Retrieve results of a standard query
 */
$query = "SELECT USER_ID,USER_NAME,USER_EMAIL,USER_LEVEL,USER_REG_DATE,USER_LAST_ACCESS,USER_LAST_IP 
    FROM USERS_TBL
    LIMIT 0,20";
$results = $database->get_results( $query );
foreach( $results as $row )
{
$USER_ID = $row['USER_ID'];
$USER_NAME = $row['USER_NAME'];
$USER_EMAIL = $row['USER_EMAIL'];
$USER_LEVEL = $row['USER_LEVEL'];
$USER_REG_DATE = $row['USER_REG_DATE'];
$USER_LAST_ACCESS = $row['USER_LAST_ACCESS'];
$USER_LAST_IP = $row['USER_LAST_IP'];

}
```

Notice that in mysqli version I have to assign each variable to another one so I can use them in different places in the code, but in my old code , I just need to type the variable inside the  while (list(....)) methods .. instead of making each variables in separate line....changing the while(list()) methods to foreach() method will cost me hundreds of hours to apply this changes in my whole codes of 3000+ PHP files 600,000 lines of code .

So , How to apply current methods code in mysqli version ???

if I can get example of fetching result in while(list()) way using MYSQLI ,I will be much appreciated.

Comment: did you try to override default php functions? Just override all of the mysql_fetch_assoc() and mysql_query() to use your own.

Comment: This code is so scaring that I doubt any improvement will make it better

Comment: @random21 , I have changed the current functions to match mysqli version, but its throw out many errors , and mainly : Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli .

Comment: mysqli_error expects you to pass it a connection. if you make your connection a global variable, like $conn, you can change your mysql_query($query) to be {mysqli_query($conn, $query)} and your mysql_error() to be {mysqli_error($conn)};